# I'm getting a make error in vmlinux.o while compiling linux kernel

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation, kernel, system-calls

I am trying to add a System call in Linux. I was following this site for the steps -https://dev.to/jasper/adding-a-system-call-to-the-linux-kernel-5-8-1-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-2ga8

My current kernel version is `5.15.0-58-generic`, and I am adding a system call to a new version `5.15.2`  which I untarred and wanted to compile.
After making all the changes in the makefile and writing my System call, I ran this command `make -j4`
and I see the file vmlinux created in my folder but I get the following error :

```
UPD include/generated/compile.h
AR init/built-in.a
LD  vmlinux.o

ld: cannot find block : file format not recognized
make: *** [Makefile: 1183: vmlinux] Error 1
```

I tried reading the exact line in the Makefile that caused the error but I am not sure how to solve it.

```
1182 vmlinux: scripts/link-vmlinux.sh autoksyms_recursive $(vmlinux-deps) FORCE
1183         +$(call if_changed_dep,link-vmlinux)
```

Comment: Run `make VERBOSE=1` (without `-j` option). That way it will print the exact command line which is executed, with all variables and macros expanded. Add this command line into the question post.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, I found the problem  , turns out `block/` was missing   in  this line   `kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ `  in the Makefile